# Is there a way to toggle what modules are included when building the app with ng build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Suppose we have an AppModule module and two other modules (ModuleA and ModuleB) in our project and want to have sort of "feature toggle" configuration option to control what modules will be included in the built code (i.e. the files in dist folder).

Comment: If this is possible to do somehow, we'll also need some way to inject dependencies conditionally. i.e to use the features of ModueA in the app depending whether the moduleA is included in the build or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in couple of ways :

1- Using the router and lazy loading your modules
For this, if your module doesn't have any view or component and is purely configuration, you can create a child view and hide it and then use the Router to load the module that you want.

2- Dynamically load the module that you want through dynamic loading ( google it).